# Reaction rate constants for the inhibition of cholinesterases by various carbamates

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, aromatic-compounds, proteins, enzymes

Darvesh et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jm8002075)] have conducted a study on the anticholinesterase activity of various carbamates derived from phenothiazine. The authors measured the inhibition rate constants of rivastigmine for acetylcholinesterase and butyrylcholinesterase as $\pu{1.13E3 M^-1 min^-1}$ and $\pu{129E3 M^-1 min^-1},$ respectively.

I want to see how the anticholinesterase activity of the different compounds studied by the authors compares to that of more traditional carbamates. What are the AChE and BuChE inhibition rate constants for pyridostigmine, neostigmine, [TL-599](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL-599), their uncharged analogs, and carbaryl?

#### Reference

1. Darvesh, S.; Darvesh, K. V.; McDonald, R. S.; Mataija, D.; Walsh, R.; Mothana, S.; Lockridge, O.; Martin, E. Carbamates with Differential Mechanism of Inhibition Toward Acetylcholinesterase and Butyrylcholinesterase. *J. Med. Chem.* **2008**, 51 (14), 4200–4212. DOI: [10.1021/jm8002075](https://doi.org/10.1021/jm8002075).